# javascript How 'new' keyword affects 'Date' return values

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

I have been <strike>using this for comparing dates on IE and other browser</strike> but
could anyone explain me how this works differently?

---

`Date()` and `Date("2014-08-05T07:47:02.051Z")`

Have different result on:

`new Date()` and `new Date("2014-08-05T07:47:02.051Z")`

---

And is there any problem that will pop?

### Edit

When I execute
`console.log(Date(expiryDate),Date())`
It just gives the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ES5 spec](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.2) makes it pretty clear:

> When `Date` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the current time .

If you want an actual `Date` instance you'll have to call it with the `new` operator. If you are happy with just a string representation of the date you don't need to bother with the `new` operator.

In other words, if you need to be able to call methods on your date (such as `getTime` or `setHours`) you'll need to use `new Date` but if you only want a string you can just use `Date`.

Comment: `console.log(Date(expiryDate),Date())` yields same value. so my code above(on question) does not really work when comparing dates strings.